# cURL command to NSURLRequest

Tags: php, iphone, curl, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I want to convert cURL command:

curl -F 'access=xxxx' \
     -F 'message=Hello.' \
     -F 'picture=@1.jpg' \
     https://example.com

to a NSURLRequest.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a request with POST data, I suggest you to use ASIHTTPRequest: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest

It is quite powerful and easy to use, you should take a look at the ASIFormDataRequest class (see the How To Use section).

I've never used it for SSL connections though, but I'm pretty sure it's possible.

Comment: I am ASIHTTPRequest but I am not being able to upload the picture to Facebook.

I use the following line of code

NSString *pngName = @"bubble";
NSString *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.png", pngName] ];
[request setFile:pngPath forKey:@"picture"];

I have checked that the file is there at the place I expect it to be. Can you please help?

Comment: Well hard to say with so few information. What is exactly the problem you have when uploading?
Maybe posting some more code would be useful too. What is documentsDirectory?

Comment: This is the document directory:

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                 NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *pngName = @"bubble"; NSString *pngPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.png", pngName] ]; 

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setFile:pngPath forKey:@"picture"];
//Tried this too
//[request setPostValue:pngPath forKey:@"picture"];

[request startSynchronous];


Please help :)

Comment: Well these lines seem ok, so you should check every step: is pngPath correct? Don't you need to send more POST data? What does the request return (done, failed, status code...)?
Maybe you should create a new question with your code properly formatted and give as much information as you can about what happens when you run it.